# PHP MySQL connection fails

Tags: php, mysql

I am testing the connection in php

```
mysql_connect("xxx.com", "usernamehere", "passwordhere") or die('cannot connect : '. mysql_error());
```

But the connection fails and shows 
[ cannot connect : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysqldb' ]

Since in my php page, I try to login with a username and pw but the error message indicates that is an anonymous login. I am not sure why it happens.

Additional information: I can login successfully when I am using my home Wifi. The problem only occurs with office Wifi.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [mysql-* functions are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 4):

change this

```
mysql_connect("mysqldb", "usernamehere", "passwordhere") or die('cannot connect : '. mysql_error());
              ^ // here it should be hostname not the DB name
```

to

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "usernamehere", "passwordhere") or die('cannot connect : '. mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mysqldb",$conn);
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake for the parameter of mysql_connect. But I used hostname in my code and I rewrote wrongly in posting my question. Sorry for the mistake and the problem still exists. I dont know why the error indicates that I am connecting @ localhost instead of @ xxx.com

Comment: @user1020390 If your code is in the same server then use localhost for the hostname. And if you are connecting to some other remote host then give the name of that server as hostname `eg. xxx.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The code is on my local machine so I am connecting to some other remote host. I put the name of that server as hostname (such as xxx.com) in my original code. It shows the error message [ cannot connect : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysqldb' ] which confuses me because I had provided the hostname, username and pw to connect.

Comment: @user1020390 this indicates that this user is not having remote access credentials. You have to give this credentials from server.

Comment: Indeed mysql by default only allows connections from localhost. If you need to connect to a different host like you are, you have to set up the appropriate credentials on that host.  You probably also have to modify the mysql configuration file to allow remote connections.  One other thing, I recommend not using xxx.com as a generic hostname.  Use example.com or something.  xxx means something you probably don't intend.